# Creating a directive using a variable value

Tags: angular, templates, variables, components, angular2-directives

I have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'appControlPanel',
    templateUrl: './control-panel.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./control-panel.component.css'],
    template: `<ng-container *ngFor="let selector of Directives.selectors">
                    <{{selector.type}} [attributes]="{{selector.attributes}}">
                <ng-container>`
})
export class ControlPanelComponent {
    private Directives;
    constructor() {
        this.Directives = [{
            selectors: [{
                type: 'appDirective1',
                attributes: {
                    'key': 1
                    'connection': false
                }
            },{
                type: 'appDirective2',
                attributes: {
                    'key': 2
                    'connection': true
                }
            }]
        }, {
            selectors: [{
                type: 'appDirective3',
                attributes: {
                    'key': 4
                    'connection': false
                }
            },{
                type: 'appDirective4',
                attributes: {
                    'key': 2
                    'connection': false
                }
            },{
                type: 'appDirective5',
                attributes: {
                    'key': 1
                    'connection': true
                }

            }]
        }];
    }
}
```

I want to create the following directives(appDirective1, appDirective2, ..., appDirective5). In order to create them dymically, I created a property that holds all the directives names and attributes that are going to get passed.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I create those directives using a variable and if that is even possible or good practice. Any inputs would be apprecciated!

Comment: What is that which you are trying to achieve , you wanna repeat the directive based on *ngFor ? if so why not create a separate directive and repeat it .

Comment: @faizan, I want to use this way since in a near future I might need to recreate, implement or reorder these directives. That’s why I held them in an object where my component handles their distribution and execution.